# Addition/Multiplication/Division are off in Java

Tags: java

```
package Calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    double answer;

    System.out.println("Enter your operation: ");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

    double fstNum = inputArray[0];
    double sndNum = inputArray[4];
    char op = inputArray[2];

    switch (op) {
        case '+': answer = fstNum + sndNum;
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + answer);
        break;

        case '-': answer = fstNum - sndNum;
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + answer);
        break;

        case '*': answer = fstNum * sndNum;
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + answer);
        break;

        case '/': answer = fstNum / sndNum;
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + answer);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

So I wrote this simple calculator, which is working perfectly fine, aside from the fact that my answers from anything except from subtraction are way off. E.g. 5 * 2 = 2650.0. I'm pretty new at programming so if I made a really basic mistake, please don't bash on me :)

Comment: Hint: the character '1', doesn't have the numeric value 1. http://unicode-table.com

Comment: ...and what happens if I enter "1+1" or "10 + 10" ? ;-)

Comment: char num1Char = inputArray[0];
    char num2Char = inputArray[4];
  
    double num1Double = num1Char;
    double num2Double = num2Char;

This is still off

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this :

```
double fstNum = Double.valueOf(new String(new char[] {inputArray[0]}));
double sndNum = Double.valueOf(new String(new char[] {inputArray[4]}));
```

because it converts the chars to strings which become converted to doubles

Answer (score 0):

For mathematical operations I recommend using java.math.BigDecimal because the basic types of java use algorithms that do not always correspond with reality or something like that.

I have added an example of how the sum also fails and how to solve the multiplication (1.1 + 0.11 = 1.2100000000000002)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    BigDecimal answer;
    double a = 1.1;
    double b = 0.11;
    System.out.println("try: " + (a+b));

    System.out.println("Enter your operation: ");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

    BigDecimal fstNum = new BigDecimal("" + inputArray[0]);
    BigDecimal sndNum = new BigDecimal("" + inputArray[4]);
    char op = inputArray[2];

    switch (op) {
        case '*': answer = fstNum.multiply(sndNum);
        System.out.println("The answer is*: " + answer);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```